# CoilImageGetter doesn't load images to AndroidView

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am trying to view an HTML content in my **Compose** HTML View using **AndroidView**..
I use this [library](https://github.com/Commit451/coil-imagegetter) to load images asynchronously using Coil.

**1) My HTML text with  tag i want to load**

```
"<p>some dummy text.</p><p>some dummy text.</p><p>some dummy text.</p>
<br><img src=\"https://example.com/PublishingImages/333.png\" alt=\"\" 
style=\"margin&#58;5px;\" /><br><br></p>"
```

**2) My HTMLView**

```
fun HtmlText(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  html: String,
  textStyle: TextStyle = contentStyle,
  okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = koinInject()
) {
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier,
    update = {
        it.text = fromHtml(
            it.context,
            okHttpClient,
            html
        )
    },
    factory = { context ->
        TextView(context).apply {
            textSize = textStyle.fontSize.value
        }
    }
  )
}
```

**3) fromHtml method**

```
fun fromHtml(
  context: Context,
  okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
  html: String
): Spannable = parse(context, okHttpClient, html, sourceModifier).apply {
  removeLinksUnderline()
  styleBold(context)
}

private fun parse(
  context: Context,
  okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
  html: String
): Spannable = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
  html,
  HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT,
  ImageGetter(context, okHttpClient, sourceModifier),
  null
) as Spannable
```

**4) ImageGetter**

```
class ImageGetter(
  val context: Context,
  okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
) : Html.ImageGetter {
  
  private fun getLoader(): ImageLoader {
    return ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
        .respectCacheHeaders(false)
        .logger(DebugLogger())
        .build()
  }

  override fun getDrawable(source: String?): Drawable {
     val drawablePlaceholder = DrawablePlaceHolder(context)

    getLoader().enqueue(
        ImageRequest.Builder(context)
            .data(finalSource)
            .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
            .target { drawable ->
                drawablePlaceholder.updateDrawable(drawable)
            }
            .build(),
    )

    // Since this loads async, we return a "blank" drawable, which we update later
    return drawablePlaceholder
  }
}
```

**My Observations**

1. Image loads from server (or from cache) correctly.
2. However, the TextView doesn't get updated after the image is loaded.
3. I think since the image *drawablePlaceholder* is empty at start, the TextView starts with no text. But after the image is retrieved, it is not updated.

How can I fix this issue??